# Select statement is not working and cannot read from SQL database in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server

After the button click event I wrote this:

```
Dim dbo As New Class1 
dbo.connect()    
dbo.objcomm.CommandText="select * from Employee where Emp_Code ="' &TextBox1.Text&"'"
dbo.objread .Read()
TextBox2.Text=dbo.objread.GetValue(1)    
End Sub
```

What it should do is that it should take the second value in the Employee and display it in the textbox after clicking on the buttton. 
However, nothing happens when I click.

I'm sure that the code is correct and that nothing is missing so what could possibly be the reason that the code is not working?

I have tried it in other applications and it worked fine. Now it is not.

Comment: Well I think your code isn't correct at all: change this: `Emp_Code ="' &TextBox1.Text&"'"` to this: `Emp_Code ='" &TextBox1.Text&"'"` see the difference?

Comment: Not only do you have a syntax error in your code, your query is going to give your DBA agida and it's vulnerable to SQL injection attack.